# How to compare three mainstream Network libraries? (Network performance comparison metrics)

Tags: java, benchmarking, rmi, load-testing, apache-mina

I am working on a research project, in which i create simple Real-time applications with three mainstream network libraries **Krynet**, **Apache Mina** and **Java-RMI**. 
For the conclusion i need to produce some benchmark kind of thing to strengthen my findings and my arguments.

I found lot of full-fledged  commercial tools and products to measure network performance on professional level but i don't have that much formal requirement and time.

Can somebody share ideas how can i do that in an easier way, which software/library or way can be use and what could be the possible metrics.

Many thanks,

Jibbylala

Comment: What is krynet?  Google and Wikipedia gave me no relevant hits.

Answer (score 0):

> For the conclusion i need to produce some benchmark kind of thing to strengthen my findings and my arguments.

You need to say what you are trying to determine from your benchmarking.

My gut feeling is that there are no generic benchmark frameworks or libraries that would allow you to compare the performance of an application across a number of middleware technologies.

Your best bet is to implement this yourself; e.g. by adding monitoring hooks to your code at the appropriate places to capture the time taken to perform each request .... or whatever it is you are trying to benchmark.

Comment: any meaningful thing and overall performance with each library

Comment: @static void main - you need to define what you mean by "overall performance".  If you can't clearly define what it is you are trying to measure, you won't get any meaningful measurements.

Comment: anything bandwidth consumption, latency, overall resource consumption etc by which i can compare these libraries metrics could be any, i just need some easy idea to compare them quantitatively.

Comment: Latency can be measured by capturing timestamps (e.g. using `System.getTimeMillis()`) and logging them.  Overall resource consumption and bandwidth consumption are hard to measure in Java.

Comment: can you please elaborate your idea more. how i can realize that... will that include the time need to serialize  or some other operation time also in case of receiving bytebuffer, etc P.S i meant i create the same application using those three libraries not use all three libraries in one application.

Comment: I don't know what more there is to say.  At specific appropriate points in your code (chosen by yourself), call getTimeMillis (etc) to get the timestamp and write a line to your log file.  Then read the file and use the timestamps to figure out how long various tasks took.